# How to display whole number for matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to show the whole number like 4 not 4.0. I am not sure what is wrong with my code. Thank you! This is my code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. If you think there's something wrong with your code and you want people to help you, it's usually recommended to share your code first.

Comment: to be more specific, could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry! I upload my code now.

Comment: Can you please edit your code into your question as text (cut and paste, then use indentation or triple-backticks to format it as code) rather than as a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing “wrong” with your code. The printing method in R tries to
make things easy to read and to save space at the same time. Sometimes it
works well, other times not.

In your example, there is a decimal number in each column of the matrix and
thus a decimal is used in the printing for the matrix for the integer values.
(really, all the values are numeric, not integer).

```r
Sigma <- matrix(c(4, -0.9, -0.9, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL)
Sigma
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]  4.0 -0.9
#> [2,] -0.9  2.0
```

Look at a matrix with just integer values – no decimals

```r
matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    3
#> [2,]    2    4
```

But if one value needs a decimal you’ll get a similar number of decimal
points within the column

```r
matrix(c(1, 2, 3.333, 4), nrow = 2)
#>      [,1]  [,2]
#> [1,]    1 3.333
#> [2,]    2 4.000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If you *really* need different formatting you can start from `apply(Sigma,c(1,2),format)`

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try this then:

```
 x <- "4"
 cat(x, "\n")
```

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help, but until the OP clarifies what they want,  answering on the basis of guesses is just muddying the waters (I won't say I haven't done that myself too, but I try to restrain myself)